# ImportError when using web.py with new environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, web.py

I just recreated all my python environment, reinstalled python and setuptools, and installed virtualenv.
I started a test enviroment with `virtualenv --no-site-packages test`, activated it with `Scripts\activate.bat` and then `easy_install web.py`.
Then I create a `code.py` file:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/.*', 'index',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
     def GET(self):
            return 'ok'

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

And I get the following error:

```
File "...\code.py", line 1, in <module>
import web
ImportError: No module named web
```

But if I use the interactive shell it works:

```
>>> import web
>>>
```

Everything done in the same cmd with the enviroment activated.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Edit:

It happens for every package installed within the environment. First it was web.py, now BeautifulSoup (same issue, cant find module, but import works in python shell)

Edit2:

The activate script is not setting the new python executable and the pythonpath `print sys.executable` gives `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Windows was configured to open .py files with `C:\Python27\python.exe`. I can even remember setting this mannualy some time ago so I wouldn't have to use `python` to run files (oh lazyness, what have you done to me?).

That's why it was working with the interactive shell, but not by executing the code.py file.

Running the file using `python code.py` works perfectly.